# VBA equality mistmatch?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA code:

```
For q = 1 To pf.PivotItems.Count
        For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
                If pf.PivotItems(q).Name = myArray(i) Then same = True
        Next i
        pf.PivotItems(q).Visible = False
        If same = True Then pf.PivotItems(q).Visible = True
        same = False

Next q
```

This line gives me an equality mismatch error: `If pf.PivotItems(q).Name = myArray(i)`

Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: What kind of array is myArray?

Comment: How are you populating `myArray`?  Have you tried using `Debug.Print` or the Immediate Window to check what the values actually are at run-time?

Comment: Also, have you considered using `Join` and `InStr` to replace the loop and `same` entirely?  (`If InStr("|" & Join(myArray, "|") & "|", "|" & pf.PivotItems(q).Name & "|") > 0 Then pf.PivotItems(q).Visible = True`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I've tweaked the code for efficiency. As mentioned in the comments, the main question is what is in myArray? it needs to output a single value, not an array or object, so you might need to further qualify myArray(i)

```
Dim pvtItm As PivotItem    'put this with other dim statements

For Each pvtItm In pf.PivotItems
    pvtItm.Visible = True
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If pvtItm.Name = myArray(i) Then
            pvtItm.Visible = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```